# Text will not vertical-align to the top in Drupal table

Tags: theming, nodes, entities

I am trying to edit a table in my Drupal editor that has images on one row (4 `td` elements) and a second row with text (also 4 `td` elements). I have applied `vertical-align:top` to the cells in the text row and they look fine in the editor. However, when I preview the page after saving the changes, the text appears to be at different vertical alignments. I tried doing `vertical-align:middle` to see if that would help, but the same results occurred. Could this be a browser issue (I am using `IE`)? Or is there something else I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Apologies; I forgot to mention that this problem is occuring inside the Drupal CMS editor.

Comment: Since this is a CSS problem and not much of a Drupal problem, I recommend that you post this question on some other stackexchange site in the future (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `valign="top"` to the `TD` element like `<td valign="top">...</td>` and see if it works.

Comment: Unbelievably, that did the trick. I assume this issue must be due to an old version of Drupal that I am using.